# Xamarin Forms - Listview - Save PDF on tap

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms.labs, xamarin.forms.listview

When I click on the `ListItem`, which is a `.PDF`, in my `ListView`, I want to save the file locally. Each `ListItem` has a different `Uri`.

Is there any way I can do that?

[image]

Comment: So, what is the question? And what is the issue you are trying to resolve? Do you have some code that shows what you want to achieve?

Comment: My question is this,when I click pdf icon, how can I save the pdf file to the device?

Comment: Alright. I have updated your question so that it reflects your need. What have you tried yourself so far to achieve your goal? Have you got any code that you can show?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it's a bit tricky to implement from scratch a ListView onTap gesture - but you can use a nuget that gives that functionality for Xamarin Forms:

http://www.michaelridland.com/xamarin/freshessentials-for-xamarin-forms-the-must-have-nuget-for-forms/

Basically, in order to use it you can just add a property to your ListView and Bind it to a Command to your CodeBehind or ViewModel (if you're following an MVVM pattern or framework):

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyCars}" fe:ListViewItemTappedAttached.Command="{Binding ItemTapCommand}">
```

Don't forget to add this resource as property/namespace of your ContentPage tho:
xmlns:fe="clr-namespace:FreshEssentials;assembly=FreshEssentials"

Ex.

```
<ContentPage xmlns:fe="clr-namespace:FreshEssentials;assembly=FreshEssentials" ... />
```

**On Saving files** - Because Xamarin.Forms runs on multiple platforms, each with its own filesystem, there is no single approach for loading and saving files created by the user.

You can follow this guide from Xamarin to know how to do that for every platform you are targeting: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/files/#Loading_and_Saving_Files